# Run single instance of oozie coordinator workflow

Tags: scheduling, oozie, oozie-coordinator, oozie-workflow

I have a oozie coordinator which runs every 30 minutes.

But I want to run only one instance of it at a time.

(Say, if the workflow takes more than 30 minutes to complete, I don't want the next scheduled workflow to start running until the previous one finishes)

Is there a configuration property I can set in coordinator.xml to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify concurrency option for you cooridinator, i.e. how many actions can work simultaneously for given coordinator. 
You can also specify execution strategy and timeout to control if actions should be skipped, when overlapping, and which.

```
   <coordinator-app name="[NAME]" frequency="[FREQUENCY]"
                    start="[DATETIME]" end="[DATETIME]" timezone="[TIMEZONE]"
                    xmlns="uri:oozie:coordinator:0.1">
      <controls>
        <timeout>[TIME_PERIOD]</timeout>
        <concurrency>[CONCURRENCY]</concurrency>
        <execution>[EXECUTION_STRATEGY]</execution>
      </controls>
      ...
```

But as far as I know this didn't work well in Oozie version 3.3. You can try it with newer version.

Further reading: 
https://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.3.0/CoordinatorFunctionalSpec.html#a6.1.6._Coordinator_Action_Execution_Policies

Comment: AFAIK `concurrency` always worked, `execution` was fixed in V4.1 _(exact release TBC)_ and `timeout` is misleading because it does not apply to running jobs but to the "wait for dataset" coordinator clause.

Comment: By the way, I would not use `uri:oozie:coordinator:0.1` if I were you; the current schema specification is 0.5 and using a legacy version is a good way to block new features and improvements...

Comment: I am having this exact same problem, but I am running oozie coordinator 2.6. Do you know if previous versions had the same issue or is it specifically 3.3? 
"But as far as I know this didn't work well in Oozie version 3.3. You can try it with newer version"
Is this documented somewhere?